# load an angular app into a webpage and pass in server variables

Tags: angularjs

I have a standalone Angular JS Application that displays a table of data. I want to load thisapp on request in multiple places in my existing non AngularJS web site. All the angular app needs to initialise is a userguid that I have in the page when I need to load the app, my problem is how to pass this into the angular app at load.

I have tried using **"bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])"** but cannot se a way to pass the variable in, ideally I could do this **bootstrap(document, ['myApp'], variablehere);**

I can make the app load by adding the userguid variable to window and receiving it from there but this seems horrible and tied to the app.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Look into $stateProvider and its resolve property. This will make your app inject a variable or in this case a factory of user information BEFORE the app is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this.Could you point us to an example?

Comment: [Docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) [Example](https://github.com/tak215/angular-architecture/blob/master/src/dashboard/common/app.config.js)